# Pidgin: Yahoo Instant Messenger Deadline

Tags: 16.04, pidgin

For years, I've used Pidgin to instant-message people who use Yahoo Instant Messenger.

Now, in Ubuntu 16.04, I keep getting this message each time I launch pidgin:

[image]

This deadline is quickly approaching. Will a pidgin update come via the repository (automatically) before this deadline? If not, what is the best work-around?

Comment: Can't answer your question but will point out Yahoo was recently bought out by Verizon for $4.83 bn and I imagine down-scaling operations are in effect.

Comment: I suggest you ask the developers directly at https://developer.pidgin.im/query.

Comment: Seem there is no any update for yahoo messenger protocol on pidgin developer page. https://developer.pidgin.im/query?status=new&status=pending&keywords=~yahoo&col=id&col=summary&col=status&col=owner&col=type&col=milestone&order=priority In the mean time, new Yahoo messenger has not beed ready yet.
https://www.getfeedback.com/r/n9JUXsCu/q/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A replacement Yahoo! protocol plugin is in progress.  The installation instructions for both Windows and Linux are located at the bottom of the README.  I tried it about two weeks ago and my Pidgin crashed, you might have better luck as there has been a fair amount of developer activity since.

https://github.com/EionRobb/funyahoo-plusplus